# Body Background Color Won't Show Up?

Tags: css

After researching for hours I still can't get it to work.

I want to add a color or a texturey image to my site's background, but it stays white.

The relevant CSS is:

```css
#html {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#body {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;   
}
```

And the HTML. Its kinda messy because I'm a noob.:

```
<body>
    <div id="ribbon">
        <div id="container" style="height: 100%;">
            <div id="social_and_music">
                <div id="audioplayer">
                    <audio controls>
                        <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
                        <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                        Your browser does not support the audio element.
                    </audio>
                </div>
                <div id="social">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="32" height="32" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="32" height="32" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/lastfm.png" width="32" height="32" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/myspace.png" width="32" height="32" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div class="nav" id="nav1"><a href="#">HOME</a></div>
            <div class="nav" id="nav2"><a href="#">MUSIC</a></div>
            <div class="nav" id="nav3"><a href="#">SHOWS</a></div>
            <div class="nav" id="nav4"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></div>
            <div id="main_content">
                <div id="main_img"></div>
                <div id="second_image">
                    <div class="widget_iframe" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;height:200px;margin:0;padding:0;border:0;">
                        <iframe class="widget_iframe" src="http://www.reverbnation.com/widget_code/html_widget/artist_3258446?widget_id=52&posted_by=artist_3258446&pwc[design]=default&pwc[background_color]=%23333333&pwc[layout]=compact&pwc[show_map]=0&pwc[size]=fit" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">SHOWS</iframe>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="leftbox">
            <div id="imgA" class="img"></div>
            <div id="imgB" class="img"></div>
            <div id="imgC" class="img"></div>
            <div id="imgD" class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightbox">right</div>
        <div id="footer">Content for footer goes here</div>
        <div id="bottom">STEREO WARFARE COPYRIGHT 2011 ARIEL MEHRBAN</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="push"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: where is the background you are trying to set ?

Comment: `min-height` is ignored by most browsers

Comment: why u set `#html`, `#body` instead of html, body and where u set a background?

Comment: @ShadowCreeper, most browsers? Well, if you only count IE6 and below, you're right.

Comment: Please show your HTML code!

Comment: blackbee's solution does work in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BDYhE/

Answer (score 4):

i think your css should be:

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;   
}
```

and on the html page you should have like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

when you put a # it means u are using a id like

css:

```css
#text{
    background-color:#aaa;
}
```

html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="text"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey blackbee, when I take out the #'s in front of html and body in my CSS document, it just makes then stop working completely.

Comment: @user2430759, then there is something else going very wrong. `#html` selects an element with the id "html" like `<hr id="html"/>`. The suggested solution should work. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BNus/).

Comment: When I remove the #'s, my page doesn't scroll down to show all the content anymore.

Comment: I figured it out, it was the "overflow: hidden" in the body styling. Duh. Thanks for the help guys its working!

Comment: its because you didnot specify ur height and width. min-height:100%
but 100% with respect to what??

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the image in body tag, this should work fine in any browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body background="imagename.jpg">
<p>some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes the backround tag in body works fine. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am using my html and css code for the background color like these .

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
```

CSS

```css
wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```